# Spark is unable to read arabic characters and replacing it with "?" on reading

Tags: java, mysql, arabic, arabic-support, apache-spark-2.2

When I try to read data from DB which has Arabic characters, they are getting replaced with " ? " 
I’m using java spark 2.2 version.
Tried few things like encoding with UTF-8  but nothing worked.

Comment: Maybe try the `cp1256` AKA `Windows-1256` encoding, which is an Arabic encoding that _can_ be used with `mysql`.  There are other options it could be too though.